# How to stop date reformatting of SPLIT() output?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have content like "3 4 5; 5 6 7; 8 9 10" in a cell and I would like to split it by the semicolons so that I have "3 4 5", "5 6 7", and "8 9 10" in three cells.

SPLIT() normally does this fine, but the problem is that Google Sheets keeps on interpreting the content as a date.  Selecting "Plain Text" doesn't help because it converts the content to a date, then converts that date to a number, then displays the number as Plain Text.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aXMV5E_TY84GNPhlOzz_jJpcxmld6CRh-5dYAX5BBwY)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

If the number of groups to extract is always the same, you can use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=regexextract(A1, rept("([\d ]+)[^\d]*", 3))
```

To process all of column `A1:A`, use an array formula, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    regexextract(A1:A, rept("([\d ]+)[^\d]*", 3)) 
  ) 
)
```

If the number of groups varies, use `split()`. You can evaluate it over an array like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  split( 
    regexreplace(A1:A, "^|; ", "$0'"), 
    "; ", 
    false 
  ) 
)
```

If you cannot use `split()` for some reason, use the `regexextract()` formula but replace the `3`, which is the `number_of_repetitions` parameter to `rept()`, with a function that calculates the number of separators in the data and adds one.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a workaround:

```
=SPLIT(CONCAT("'",REGEXREPLACE(A5,"\; ","; '")),"; ",false)
```

The idea is to add a quote mark at the beginning and after each delimiter to the string, and then invoking SPLIT.  This feels very kludgey so I'm still hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: _I'm still hoping for a simpler solution._ Aren't the answers by @doubleunary simpler? Plus they have the advantage of processing an entire column of values rather than just one row.